# Liquibase integration in python project

Tags: python, mysql, oracle, mariadb, liquibase

I am planning to use Liquibase(https://www.liquibase.org) to manage the migrations/versioning of Oracle database schemas. The project is in Python using setuptools.
I have seen also Python wrappers for Liquibase but they don't seem to be well maintained.

Does anyone has experience in the integration of Liquibase in python projects? Or a similar?

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for the same requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using SQLAlchemy ? Because there is a tool to manage database migration : [Alembic](https://pypi.org/project/alembic/)

Alambic is wrapped in another Python Framwework too, like Flask in specific module as Flask-migration.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pyliquibase. you can perform liquibase actions through python script

https://github.com/memiiso/pyliquibase

Comment: Hi @shashi,   I have gone through the given URL, It is hard for me to understand that, do you have any sample demo repository?